# DB alternative for ISPC in combination with Magento2?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, magento2.4, mariadb-10.5, ispconfig

Hosting ISPC 3.2.11p1 on Debian(11) with 10.5.21-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 & nginx webserver.
Hosting multiple WordPress and static websites. Magento2 2.4.3-release was required, during install the following error occurred.

```
In SqlVersionProvider.php line 93:

  Current version of RDBMS is not supported. Used Version: 10.5.21-MariaDB-0+deb11u1. Supported versions: MySQL-8, MySQL-5.7, MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)
```

Using deprecated MySQL on VPS is not favorable. Using an external mysql-8 would be an option but costs more money.
**Is there any way to spin up an extra sql database just for Magneto2 database?**
The configuration has to be done via the command line anyway. This means a full ISPC setup for a site is not possible unlike for WordPress as it runs on this version of MariaDB.

Team of magento2 have no indication of upgrading this feature to support *older* database versions :(

On a local machine the (outdated)MariaDB was replaced for the (outdated)mysql-8 server. this caused problems in the auto install for ISPC when installing on VPS.
Using debian12 causes a lot of problems when trying to install magento2 or ISPC. WordPress has no problems except the usual. it has taken me 6 days of trying different things. I'm a little lost and could use some outside advice.

I got Magento2 running on a local ubuntu server together with WordPress, but this was pure nginx configuration and no interface like ISPC. The 3 together cause for problems on a VPS and the IPSC forum is pretty outdated on that side. I don't use docker.